# Determine when all user generated code has finished evaluating in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, eval

I have a application I am trying to setup that attempts to evaluate user generated JavaScript code using nodejs. Is there a way to determine when all native promises from the user generated code have been resolved?

The nodejs process its self has the behavior of waiting for all asynchronous code to finish executing before exiting. Is there any way to get the same behavior using either eval() or vm.runInNewContext()?

Comment: You apparently trust the users who generate the code, so why not simple tell them to return a promise that resolves when they're done?

Comment: No, there's no built-in way to do that, but you can simply wrap every asynchronous API and monitor it yourself. Several testing frameworks do that afaik.

Comment: Running untrusted code is a great way to get hacked. Are you sure you need to do that? Is this heavily sandboxed? Do you trust people to not write infinite loops? Node finishes when it thinks its done, but even well-intentioned code can hold something open by accident and prevent the process from completing successfully.

Comment: Run the code in a node.js child process.  When the child rocess exits, the code is done.